# Android - Calculator help / source wanted

Tags: android, calculator

I know Android is open source, but are all the apps that they make open source?

Is there a way I can get my hands on the Android Calculator source?

Otherwise, can someone point me in the direction to an open source calculator, or a tutorial to make one?

Thanks!

Comment: use google/youtube/iTunes U to look for tutorials. Otherwise please ask a specific question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android calculator source is browseable here: [Calculator source tree](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Calculator.git;a=tree)

Comment: That link is outdated. https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calculator

Answer (score 0):

i create an open source calculator its good for beginner android learner.
download link below :
http://sourceforge.net/projects/androidcalculat/